# looping array in javascript, variable from html

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

how i can make a loop in javascript with html variable? i using CodeIgniter

HTML

```
<td id="tot<?php=$num?>">Rp.<input type="text" name="total[]" value="<?php echo number_format($trl->harga);?>"></td>
```

JS for total and number format

```
function jumlah(num, harga, jumlah) {
        var jml = jumlah.value;
        if (jml != 0 && jml != "") {
            $("#tot"+num).text("Rp."+numeral(harga*jml).format('0,0'));
        }
        // alert(arr_num);
        total_n();
        kosong();
    }

    function total_n() {
        x = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arr_num; i++) {
            y = $("#tot"+i).text();
            y = y.replace(/\,/g,"");
            y = y.replace(/Rp./g,"");
            x += parseInt(y);
        }
        // alert(x);
        $("#total").val(numeral(x).format('0,0'));
    }
```

Comment: What is the desired output? What is the `arr_num` variable in your second function? What happens when you run that code?

Comment: sry, var arr_num = <?=$num?>; count my datas

Comment: my code will count total from variable jumlah & harga,, but if jumlah > 1, total not count

Comment: Please review [ask]